# Exclude missing data in for loop

Tags: r

this is my first time in stack overflow. Hopefully my question is specific enough for the community.

1. I have this dataset:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuO2z.png)
2. I am currently trying to visualise the distribution of this dataset using the following code:

`

```
#Create a 2 by 3 plot
par(mfrow=c(2,3))

# Plot each column one by one
for (i in 1:ncol(dataset)) {
## Select the variable
x <- dataset[, i]
plot(density(x), main=paste("x",i,": S=",round(skew(x),3),", K=",round(kurtosi(x),3),sep=""), 
   col="red", xlab="")
}
```

3. Unfortunately, because I have a missing data in my dataset, R will return the following error:

   Error in density.default(x) : 'x' contains missing values

May I know how can I get R to plot my graphs without having to manually remove all missing cases? I am completely new to R so any help will be appreciated.

Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: try: ```density(x[!is.na(x)])``` or ```x <- dataset[!is.na(dataset[,i]),i]```

Comment: if you share the output of `dput(dataset)` people will be able to check their answers with your dataset to see if it works first. You'll likely get more answers this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding na.omit():

```
x <- na.omit(dataset[, i])
```

Answer (score 0):

To judge by the picture of your data you have **empty cells** in addition to `NA` (which are however not in evidence in the screenshot). To get rid of either you can do this:

First, convert empty cells to `NA`:

```
df[df == ""] <- NA
```

Then use `na.omit`to remove rows that contain `NA` in any column:

```
df_clean <- na.omit(df)
```

DATA:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(c("", 1:5, NA), 50, replace = T),
  x2 = sample(c("", 1:5, NA), 50, replace = T),
  x3 = sample(c("", 1:5, NA), 50, replace = T),
  x4 = sample(c("", 1:5, NA), 50, replace = T))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `complete.cases`

```
 df <- replace(df, df == '', NA)
 df_clean <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```